# Call hangup take time - asterisk dialplan

Tags: asterisk

I wrote dialplan for my Asterisk system. The `extension.conf` is :

**extensions.conf**

```
[from-pstn]
exten =>s,1,Verbose(1, Caller ${CALLERID(all)} has entered the paf IVR)
    same=>n,Answer()
    same=>n,Wait(3)
    same=>n,Playback(welcome)
    same=>n,GoSub(post,ss,1)
    same=>n,Playback(thanks)
    same=>n,Hangup()

[post]
include => default_cont
exten => ss,1,Background(gud/post)
    same=>n,WaitExten(5)
exten => 1,1,Set(CDR(aa)=136)
    same=>n,Return()
exten => 2,1,Set(CDR(aa)=137)
    same=>n,Return()

[default_cont]
exten => i,1,Playback(invalid)
    same=> n,Hangup()
exten => t,1,Playback(timeout)
    same=> n,Hangup()
exten => h,1,DeadAGI(convert_recordings.sh)
    same=>n,DeadAGI(my_uploader.php,${var1},${CALLERID(num)},${CDR(var2)},${CDR(aa)})`
```

When i call to my asterisk system. it takes time to hangup after playing thanks audio file. Actually, call hangup after all AGI execution are completed and my_uploader.php execution takes time. But i need instant hangup after playing thanks message. System only executes AGI files after the call is completely hangup. How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Witch version of asterisk you are using? Since 1.6 DeadAgi is deprecated and in h exten you should use AGI instead. Can you post asterisk output for this situation? Because I suspect, that thanks message is played after `my_uploader` script.

Comment: i am using asterisk 11.9.0 and analog pstn is connected to asterisk server. thanks message plays first and my_uploader execute at last

Answer (score 0):

Thats becuase you have h extensions in your dialplan

So it will take time while you agi on h-extension ends.

You can use cdr info and run external script based on that. You can write dialplan on hexten(not agi). You can write faster(not blocking) agi.

Very likly your uploaded or conversion task take time. You have only notate somewhere in db what you have to do and do that in external thread, not in asterisk.

That way you will not block asterisk thread.

Comment: if i dont include h extension in my dialplan. How can i run my script after the call hangup?

Comment: I realise this is an old thread, but in case anyone finds this, you can run your post-call processing in the background - put `&` at the end of your command.

Comment: It still will block asterisk. Becuase & will do in background in shell, shell still have be active. You have avoid ANY proccessing in h-extension. Just save info in mysql or other queue and proccess complex/hi-latency tasks by external daemon.